# SASS playing with colors

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to reuse the primary colour to apply border based on the primary colour. Refer my code

```
h2{
  border-color:#999-100;
}

**Outputs to which i expected**

h2{
  border-color:#353535
}
```

In case if i try to use saving it into variable it throws me undefined variable.

```
$primary:#999;
 h1{
 border-color:$primary-100;
}
```

This may be simple but i'm a beginner. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hey Santosh how #999 - 100 = #353535 ??  I am also learning sass can you please explain..

Comment: I think that you want to do something like darken( $primary, 10% )

Comment: @SahilDhir that's a kind of RGB calculation...Don't know by what logic it has arrived

Comment: ok @SanthoshKumar i think you should use #100 instead of just 100 with some space , like - border-color:$primary - #100;.. I tried this code in scss and it worked.. But it does not give #353535 as output :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response at-last i found what mistake i have committed.

```
$primary:#999;
h1{
  border-color:$primary - 100;
}
```

I forgot to leave space between `$primary and 100`

Comment: Thats great .. which compiler are you using?

Comment: @SahilDhir SASS default compiler